# Several devices in Device Manager have Code 3 error

Tags: windows-7, drivers, device-manager

One of our users' machines (Dell Optiplex 380 running Windows 7 32-bit) is having a weird driver issue. A bunch of devices have Error Code 3:

> The driver for this device might be corrupted, or your system may be running low on memory or other resources. (Code 3)

The system isn't low on memory (only 1GB in use out of whatever the max for 32-bit is.)

Here's a screenshot of the affected devices:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried reinstalling the chipset and audio drivers to no avail. I have no idea what prompted it, and I'm not sure how the basic Windows Generic PnP Monitor driver could even be corrupted. What might be causing this error?

Comment: Have you ran complete virus and malware scans?

Comment: So how much total installed memory do you have in the system?

Comment: Haven't run virus scan yet - doing that now. 4GB installed.

Comment: Virus scan was clean.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and am about to attempt this article. Hope it helps you.

[The driver for this device might be corrupted (Code 3) | [EK] Technical Solutions](http://www.explosiveknowledge.net/main/2012/02/05/drvcd3/)

> Turns out if you remove a file\service called wdf01000 you will be
>   greeted with many devices with yellow ‘!’, and many will simply not
>   work.
>
> Some examples include processor drivers, CD\DVD drivers, mouse and
>   keyboard that are USB (ps/2 works fine), and sound drivers.
>
> First off, we need to restore the file wdf01000.sys to
>   C:\windows\system32\drivers. For Windows Vista\7 simply right click
>   and go to properties -> Previous Versions -> and select a previous
>   version and open it. Copy and paste the older wdf01000.sys into the
>   C:\windows\system32\drivers.
>
> Now just merge this key For Windows Vista or Windows 7 [32-bit tested
>   only]
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Wdf01000]
> “DisplayName”=”Kernel Mode Driver Frameworks service”
> “Group”=”WdfLoadGroup”
> “ImagePath”=hex(2):73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,\
> 72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c,00,57,00,64,00,66,00,30,00,31,00,30,\
> 00,30,00,30,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
> “ErrorControl”=dword:00000001
> “Start”=dword:00000000
> “Type”=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Wdf01000\Enum]
> “0″=”Root\\LEGACY_WDF01000\\0000″
> “Count”=dword:00000001
> “NextInstance”=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Wdf01000\Parameters]
> “MajorVersion”=dword:00000001
> “MinorVersion”=dword:00000009
> “BuildNumber”=dword:00001db0
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I did that for you in this case, but please remember it for the future. Thanks!